# VB.NET string manipulation -- caps to only one letter caps

Tags: vb.net, string

So I have a string "NEW".

What is the SIMPLEST way to convert that string to "New".

Basically right now I'm doing this:

```
Case "NEW"
    makes = connector.GetMakesByYear(_AuthorizationKey, "NewCar", CDate(Now), Year)
Case "USED"
    makes = connector.GetMakesByYear(_AuthorizationKey, "UsedCar", CDate(Now), Year)
```

And I would prefer not to use a case statement because it's only one parameter that needs to change, and both are appended with "Car".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the “old” string functions, you can use this:

```
result = StrConv("hello world", VbStrConv.ProperCase)
```

to convert a string to “proper case”. However, in your case this would probably result in (if I read this right) “Usercar”, not “UserCar”.

Comment: I believe Scott wants to apply the capitalization only to "New" or "Used" as a variable and then append "Car" to that variable

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
String.Format("{0}{1}", carType.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(), carType.Substring(1).ToLower())
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you plan on using often, you might consider creating an extension function for it:

```
Public Module ObjectExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function firstLetterToUpper(ByVal s As String) As String
        Return Char.ToUpper(s.First()) + New String(s.Skip(1).Select(Function(x) Char.ToLower(x)).ToArray())
    End Function
End Module
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
"USED".firstLetterToUpper()
```

Which returns "Used"

Obviously you can change the function body with something more efficient like Guilherme's or Konrad's answer, but making an extension function for this can be quite useful if you do plan on doing something like this often, or if you are just a fan of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have done!

```
Function InitUpperCase(ByVal str As String) As String
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then
        Return str
    End If
    Dim charlist() As Char = str.ToCharArray
    charlist(0) = Char.ToUpper(charlist(0))
    Return New String(charlist)
End Function
```

to see Output

```
MessageBox.Show(InitUpperCase("my first letter"))
```